# Creating a Nested/Loop Calculation in Vertica (?)

Tags: sql, vertica

So maybe I'm just way over-thinking things, but is there any way to replicate a nested/loop calculation in Vertica with just SQL syntax.

Explanation -

In Column AP I have remaining values per month by an attribute key, in column CHANGE_1M I have an attribution value to apply.

The goal is for future values to calculate the preceding Row partition AP*CHANGE_1M, by the subsequent row partition CHANGE_1M to fill in the future AP values.

For reference I have 15,000 Keys Per Period and 60 Periods Per Year in the full-data set.

Sample Calculation

Period 5 =
(Period4_AP * Period5_CHANGE_1M)+Period4_AP

Period 6 =
(((Period4_AP * Period5_CHANGE_1M)+Period4_AP)*Period6_CHANGE_1M)
+
((Period4_AP * Period5_CHANGE_1M)+Period4_AP)

ect.

Sample Data on Top

Expected Results below

[image: Sample Data]

[image: Result Set]

Comment: Edit your question and provide both sample data and desired results.  Fewer rows would probably help as well.  Also, a clear explanation of the calculation would help.  It would also help if you had a simple period counter to enumerate the rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated as requested.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff    ~Thanks for your input, I solved this a couple of months ago and forgot to do a follow-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time no see - I should have returned to answer this question earlier.

I got so stuck on thinking of the programmatic way to solve this issue, I inherently forgot it is a math equation, and where you have math functions you have solutions.

Basically this question revolves around doing table multiplication.

The solution is to simply use LOG/LN functions to multiply and convert back using EXP.

Snippet of the simple solve.

Hope this helps other lost souls, don't forget your math background and spiral into a whirlpool of self-defeat.

---

EXP(SUM(LN(DEGREDATION)) OVER (ORDER BY PERIOD_NUMBER ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)) AS DEGREDATION_RATE

** Controlled by what factors/attributes you need the data stratified by with a PARTITION

---

Basically instead of starting at the retention PX/P0, I back into with the degradation P1/P0 - P2/P1 ect.

---

| PERIOD_NUMBER | DEGRADATION | DEGREDATION_RATE | DEGREDATION_RATE x 100000 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100.00% | 100.00% | 100000.00 |  |
| 1 | 57.72% | 57.72% | 57715.18 |  |
| 2 | 60.71% | 35.04% | 35036.59 |  |
| 3 | 70.84% | 24.82% | 24820.66 |  |
| 4 | 76.59% | 19.01% | 19009.17 |  |
| 5 | 79.29% | 15.07% | 15071.79 |  |
| 6 | 83.27% | 12.55% | 12550.59 |  |
| 7 | 82.08% | 10.30% | 10301.94 |  |
| 8 | 86.49% | 8.91% | 8910.59 |  |
| 9 | 89.60% | 7.98% | 7984.24 |  |
| 10 | 86.03% | 6.87% | 6868.79 |  |
| 11 | 86.00% | 5.91% | 5907.16 |  |
| 12 | 90.52% | 5.35% | 5347.00 |  |
| 13 | 91.89% | 4.91% | 4913.46 |  |
| 14 | 89.86% | 4.41% | 4414.99 |  |
| 15 | 91.96% | 4.06% | 4060.22 |  |
| 16 | 89.36% | 3.63% | 3628.28 |  |
| 17 | 90.63% | 3.29% | 3288.13 |  |
| 18 | 92.45% | 3.04% | 3039.97 |  |
| 19 | 94.95% | 2.89% | 2886.43 |  |
| 20 | 92.31% | 2.66% | 2664.40 |  |
| 21 | 92.11% | 2.45% | 2454.05 |  |
| 22 | 93.94% | 2.31% | 2305.32 |  |
| 23 | 89.66% | 2.07% | 2066.84 |  |
| 24 | 94.12% | 1.95% | 1945.26 |  |
| 25 | 95.83% | 1.86% | 1864.21 |  |
| 26 | 92.31% | 1.72% | 1720.81 |  |
| 27 | 96.97% | 1.67% | 1668.66 |  |
| 28 | 90.32% | 1.51% | 1507.18 |  |
| 29 | 90.00% | 1.36% | 1356.46 |  |
| 30 | 94.44% | 1.28% | 1281.10 |  |
| 31 | 94.12% | 1.21% | 1205.74 |  |
| 32 | 100.00% | 1.21% | 1205.74 |  |
| 33 | 90.91% | 1.10% | 1096.13 |  |
| 34 | 90.00% | 0.99% | 986.52 |  |
| 35 | 94.44% | 0.93% | 931.71 |  |
| 36 | 100.00% | 0.93% | 931.71 |  |

Answer (score 1):

Vertica does not have (yet?) the `RECURSIVE WITH` clause, which you would need for the recursive calculation you seem to be needing here.

Only possible workaround would be tedious: write (or generate, using perl or Python, for example) as many nested queries as you need iterations.

I'll only want to detail this if you want to go down that path.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought. I mapped out a long-term path of passing the data through to my DW team to then pass through python to run the recursive calculations and pass it back to me during ETL. (I was hoping I could avoid since I can't write data to the DW with any scripts in an automated manner.) I may be back in 6 months when my DW team gets to the ticket. :(